# Installing gjh solver using conda

Tags: symbolic-math, solver, non-linear-regression, ampl, pyomo

How do I install the AMPL gjh solver using conda on Windows?

I am trying to install this to conduct sensitivity analysis on Pyomo. Ultimately, I am trying to conduct parameter estimation on Pyomo and get the least squares' sensitivities on the parameters themselves.

The difficulty is that the parameters themselves do not appear in the objective function explicitly. The parameters only affect the predictions indirectly via the DAE that describes my system of interest. This means symbolic differentiation is probably not an option.

Comment: I think you have to download that from the AMPL website or Netlib and then compile it yourself. This is unrelated to Python.

Comment: I see, turns out the solver is written in C "gjh.c". To compile it myself, I would have to use a windows compiler like MinGW. I am not yet familiar with compiling codes. I hope that I would be able to compile the code and add the solver to my anaconda environment on my own. Or, if you would be so kind, could you guide me on the basic steps I would need to do in order to compile it and add it to my windows conda environment?